# How to replace the content of the parent div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, parent

i have this html code:

```
<div id="ht_key" class="ht_all">
    <div class="ht_bottom">
        <div class="ht_bottom_p">
            <span class="ht_bottom_o">
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="htrc('key');\">click</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code may be seen in the page 5-6 times(or more).
I want from the htrc function to replace the #ht_key div with some other content. ("key" is different in each case). The problem is that if in the page there are 2 divs with same "key" then when the htrc function takes place, then only the first #ht_key div is replaced. So since i need to replace the content of the #ht_key div where the a (from which the htrc function is called) was clicked, is there any way to replace its parent div(the parent div which has id)?

I have tried both parent and closest but none of these returned the result. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make the `ht_key` a `class` instead of an `id`.

```
<div class="ht_key ht_all">
```

This way your HTML is valid.

Or change the `onclick` to pass `this`, and do a `closest()` up to `ht_all`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="htrc(this);">click</a>
```

*js*

```
htrc( el ) {
    $(el).closest('.ht_all');
    // ...
}
```

If you take this approach, the I'd use a HTML5 `data-` attribute for the `ht_key`:

```
<div data-key="somekey" class="ht_all">
```

And if you're using the latest versions of jQuery, you can do:

```
htrc( el ) {
    var $all = $(el).closest('.ht_all');
    var key = $all.data('key');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume #ht_key is actually a parent for an anchor (in which case you are missing closing tag in your snippet). I would remove "onclick" and bind the event handler like this:

```
$("span.ht_bottom_o a").click(function(){$(this).closest(".ht_all").html(...)});
```